# Content Database grew out of control

Tags: content-database, database

A user did a for loop in his workflow and I dont know what was wrong but it blew up the server by taking all the resources. Fixed that, but now the content DB is very large. Its like 70gbs with a 20 quota.

Tried an orphaned item script.. nothing

tried to empty the recycle bin with a script... it just runs forever.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44702/discussion-on-question-by-renton-blackstone-content-database-grew-out-of-control).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Worfklow cause the damaged and create tons of items in the Workflow History List( AllUSerTable) also audit table get hit.

- Now you can delete the items from Workflow List then removed them from the Recyclbins
- Also you have to trim the [audit log using the pwoershell](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2012/09/05/how-to-trim-audit-logs-in-sharepoint-20072010/).

  $site = Get-SPSite http://yoursitecollectionURL
  $date = Get-Date “22/08/2012”
  $site.Audit.DeleteEntries($date)
- Now Shrink the Database, you do it via central admin their is Health Analyzer rule which check if any content DB has large free space.

Comment: So I ran a script to clean out the recycle bins on the site and it just kept running for about two hours and I left for the day (closing my session and thus ending the script). Next morning my coworker said look at the DB and low and behold it went down 10gb's and deleted most of the audit log. So I am running the script again and jsut letting it run till it finishes.

Comment: And that corrupted the database to a 500 error and took up all the resources on the server and now we are rolling to backup. :(

Comment: thats bad, which script you run, trim? i think you kill the script intially while it is running major reason.

Comment: No it was just a script to empty the recycle bins. I thought it was working. Luckily SharePoint is pretty steady and slowly repaired its self. Its working condition right now and I am taking a hammer to the QA copy of the database to try and fix it.

Comment: ok good,For future...Never run the script into the production without testing. Also never interrupts the script, in many cases it cause the orphan or corruption. Mostly over here, we share our experiences and thoughts on the bases of experience which may not work well with you. So always advised to test the things 1st.

Comment: the script given didnt work either

Comment: Ok.. so I got it down to 26gbs but the AllUserData table is still 16 gbs.. It is full of duplicates. How do i get that to come down?

Comment: did you clean the workflow history list

Comment: So i actually got this to go away by running the sharepoint health analyzer tool to truncate the database, BUT... it does not actually show results until you reboot the server.

Comment: thats strange, there will be something over there otherwise it should work without reboot. have u run reanalyze?

Comment: oh yeah.. ran reanlyze several times. This does the same thing with the user profile db when it gets a bunch of empty space I will run the truncate (form SP Health) and then it wont show the freed up space until reboot. EVEN.. with WSS_logging wipes out a bunch of space I also have to reboot before it will show the space empty on the servers.

Comment: strange, but it is what it is...i often called it SharePoint way :)...but glad, you issue resolved. if things are helpful, please mark them answer with upvote.